# Convert transposed NumPy array to CvMat type in Python using cv.fromarray

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am having a problem where some numpy arrays don't convert to cvMat using cv.fromarray().  It appears the problem occurs whenever the numpy array has been transposed.

```
import numpy as np
import cv

# This works fine:
b = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3).astype('float32')
B = cv.fromarray(b)
print(cv.GetSize(B))

# But this produces an error:
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2).astype('float32')
b = a.T
B = cv.fromarray(b)
print(cv.GetSize(B))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test_err.py", line 17, in <module>
    B = cv.fromarray(b)
TypeError: cv.fromarray array can only accept arrays with contiguous data
```

Any suggestions?  Many of my arrays have been transposed at some point so the error is coming up frequently.

I'm using Python2.7 on MacOS X Lion with NumPy 1.6.2 and OpenCV 2.4.2.1 installed from MacPorts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check your arrays using the `flags.contiguous` attribute, and if they are not, make them be using `copy()`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> a.flags.contiguous
True
>>> b = a.T
>>> b.flags.contiguous
False
>>> b = b.copy()
>>> b.flags.contiguous
True
```

When you ask for a transpose, numpy doesn't actually transpose the data, only the strides used to access it, unless you specifically trigger a copy with `copy()`.